# facebook like button text align iframe javascript

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, text-alignment, text-align

i am adding a facebook like button to my site but the text-align won't go to the right hand side. i have no idea how i could do it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Here is an example of the code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding text-align: right to the style attribute inside the iframe element:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="text-align: right; border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```